# How to code a graph drawing utility in linux

Tags: python, graph, gtk, gnuplot

I am working on a project in which I have to develop a tool which can plot data traffic on various nodes on my network. I can't use Xgraph or Gnuplot since I myself have to create a tool. I have a fair knowledge of GTK and python. I am wondering how I can collect the traffic data using python and draw a very basic graph with data on y-axis time on x-axis and display it using gtk gui.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with "I myself have to create a tool." Your easiest solution is to use a library such as Gnuplut or matplotlib or even Google Charts to render an image which you display in your program.

Comment: Sounds like homework going by "I myself have to create a tool.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use GTK. Your assignment specifies a "graph", which is a subset of "picture". Use the same tools you would use to draw a picture out of rectangles, lines, and textboxes.

The [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) can [help you draw images](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) [Python API](http://www.cairographics.org/pycairo/) for that, which is tightly integrated in GTK. You'll then just need to draw in a GtkDrawingArea using the cairo API. Beware that the Python bindings have changed since GTK 3, you'll have to use [PyGobject](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) instead of pyGTK.

Comment: thank you guys for your reply but at the moment my main problem is HOW TO COLLECT THE TRAFFIC DATA..plotting will be the next step..basically i want to collect data that means how many bytes transfered between two pcs on my network in a given time thereafter creating two fields in a text file first one time second one data transfered and then plotting will be done of these two fields..